# Changing Contents Of Array Results In Dangling Pointer

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, nsarray

I've got a globablly defined `array` which includes a lot of emojis/strings at the top of my `ViewController` class.

```
var emojis: [[String : Any]] = 
[["name": "Recently used emojis", "emojis" : []], ["name": "header2", "emojis" : ["g", "Y", "U", "g", "2", "2", "2" ,"2" ," 2" ," 2", "2" ,"2", "42", "32", "2", "32", "23", "23", "1", "1", "1", "2", "g", "2", "2", "2" ,"2" ," 2" ," 2", "2" ,"2", "42", "32", "2", "32", "23", "23", "2", "1", "2", "gk", "tT"]], ["name": "header3 and a bit more text", "emojis" : ["g", "Y", "U", "g", "2", "2", "2" ,"2" ," 2" ," 2", "2" ,"2", "42", "32", "2", "32", "23", "23", "1", "1", "1", "2", "g", "2", "2", "2" ,"2" ," 2" ," 2", "2" ,"2", "42", "32", "2", "32", "23", "23", "2", "1", "2", "gk", "tT"]]]
```

In the viewDidLoad method, I'm populating the "Recently used emojis in the array, since I need to access it through the `NSUserDefaults`.

```
var recentEmojiArray: Array<Any> = []
  if let prefs = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.EmojiPreferences") {
    if let defaults = prefs.dictionary(forKey: "EMFDefaultsKey"){
        if let recents = defaults["EMFRecentsKey"] as? [String]{
            recentEmojiArray.append(recents)
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I'm adding the recently used emojis to the array and will reload the data in my collectionView.

```
emojis[0] = ["name": "Recently used emojis", "emojis": recentEmojiArray[0]]
collectionView.reloadData()
```

However, everytime I change a value in the `emojis` array, I'm getting crashes that seem to point to a dangling pointer. Here's the latest tack trace:

(thread 1)

```
libobjc.A.dylib`_mapStrHash:
    0x10e10d756 <+0>:  xorl   %ecx, %ecx
    0x10e10d758 <+2>:  testq  %rsi, %rsi
    0x10e10d75b <+5>:  je     0x10e10d7a3               ; <+77>
    0x10e10d75d <+7>:  movb   (%rsi), %al
->  0x10e10d75f <+9>:  testb  %al, %al
    0x10e10d761 <+11>: je     0x10e10d7a3               ; <+77>
    0x10e10d763 <+13>: addq   $0x4, %rsi
    0x10e10d767 <+17>: xorl   %ecx, %ecx
    0x10e10d769 <+19>: movzbl %al, %eax
    0x10e10d76c <+22>: xorl   %eax, %ecx
    0x10e10d76e <+24>: movzbl -0x3(%rsi), %eax
    0x10e10d772 <+28>: testl  %eax, %eax
    0x10e10d774 <+30>: je     0x10e10d7a3               ; <+77>
    0x10e10d776 <+32>: shll   $0x8, %eax
    0x10e10d779 <+35>: xorl   %eax, %ecx
    0x10e10d77b <+37>: movzbl -0x2(%rsi), %eax
    0x10e10d77f <+41>: testl  %eax, %eax
    0x10e10d781 <+43>: je     0x10e10d7a3               ; <+77>
    0x10e10d783 <+45>: shll   $0x10, %eax
    0x10e10d786 <+48>: xorl   %ecx, %eax
    0x10e10d788 <+50>: movzbl -0x1(%rsi), %ecx
    0x10e10d78c <+54>: testl  %ecx, %ecx
    0x10e10d78e <+56>: je     0x10e10d7a1               ; <+75>
    0x10e10d790 <+58>: shll   $0x18, %ecx
    0x10e10d793 <+61>: xorl   %eax, %ecx
    0x10e10d795 <+63>: movb   (%rsi), %al
    0x10e10d797 <+65>: addq   $0x4, %rsi
    0x10e10d79b <+69>: testb  %al, %al
    0x10e10d79d <+71>: jne    0x10e10d769               ; <+19>
    0x10e10d79f <+73>: jmp    0x10e10d7a3               ; <+77>
    0x10e10d7a1 <+75>: movl   %eax, %ecx
    0x10e10d7a3 <+77>: movzwl %cx, %eax
    0x10e10d7a6 <+80>: movl   %ecx, %edx
    0x10e10d7a8 <+82>: shrl   $0x10, %edx
    0x10e10d7ab <+85>: xorl   %eax, %edx
    0x10e10d7ad <+87>: imull  $0xfff1, %edx, %eax       ; imm = 0xFFF1 
    0x10e10d7b3 <+93>: addl   %ecx, %eax
    0x10e10d7b5 <+95>: retq
```

The error does not occur when I delete values from the array.

What is going on here?

Comment: When is the crash happening? On `emojis[0] = ["name": "Recently used emojis", "emojis": recentEmojiArray[0]]`? Or on `collectionView.reloadData()`? If it's on `.reloadData()`, at what point? `numberOfItemsInSection`? or `cellForItemAt`? Do a little debugging, and then provide more detail.

Comment: Try to post more code which is related `collectionView` data loading?